# JavaScript Keyboard Events in IE10

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, internet-explorer-10

I have been trying to get a VBA script to dispatch a keydown event but no success... 
There is no much information on getting the 'iniKeyboardEvent'working on InternetExplorer as well..

```
Sub ie_evt()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/onkeydown.htm"
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
ie.Visible = True

Set doc = ie.Document

 doc.parentWindow.execScript ("var tb = document.getElementById('oExample')")
 doc.parentWindow.execScript ("tb.value = 'a'")
 doc.parentWindow.execScript ("var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent')")
 doc.parentWindow.execScript ("e.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 65, 0);")
 doc.parentWindow.execScript ("tb.dispatchEvent(e)")
End Sub
```

Can anyone assist me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is always dodgy at best in VBA, but you could try using Win API to send a keyboard event to the active window. 2 main points:

- Make sure the IE window is the active window at the time of sending the key event (You can use `AppActivate()` or other API methods to do this)
- You will need to know the virtual key code for the key(s) you want to 'press' [here is a list of most of them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)

Then something like this in a standard code module:

```
#If Win64 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
#Else
    Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
#End If

'// Example, send the number 5
Const NUM_5 As Byte = &H65

Sub foo()

'// your code here - ensure IE window is active window and then:

'// Send key press event
keybd_event NUM_5, 0&, 0&, 0&

'// rest of code
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but really don't want to use sendkeys... IE will not be the active window when running the complete code...

Comment: This isn't `SendKeys()` it's a Win API function that sends a keyboard event to the active window. And if you want to trigger a key press event then you're quite limited with your options